# Generating distinct random numbers from uint256 in range

Tags: random

My goal is to generate around 1500 distinct random numbers, from range 8000.

I receive (blockchain ChainLink VRF - connected to random oracle, but that's not important):

- variable array of uint256[] `randomValues`: unsigned values <0, 2^256-1>
- i convert this field right away to numbers from my range, using `( randomValues[i] MOD 8000 ) + 1`.
- Since I want to create distinct numbers, I guess I should be calling generating function until I have enough of them.

My question is if you know about more efficient way how to generate array of distinct random numbers from array of numbers like
[ 106182753482634914995248705155707514089551099076291415270692202660364749508656, 45628802998066180854454684078101263717187335597784096973096012883499998820379, .. ]?

Comment: Btw this is how that uint256 array is generated in first place:         ```expandedValues = new uint256[](n);
        for (uint256 i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            expandedValues[i] = (uint256(keccak256(abi.encode((randomNumber) + 1, i))) % 8000) + 1;
        }```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, this is more practical than theoretical, but maybe someone will find it useful. I decided to go another way on this one (using **python3** `random` module).

1. I shuffle generated list of numbers 1..10000 using Mersenne twister (MT)
2. python3 `random.shuffle()` is using Fisher-Yates shuffle; as a randomness initiator for `random` I am using large integer, I use it to seed MT
3. for 1500 list items MT needs seed of size = `log2(1500!)` bits, note that for python3 seed longer than 20.000 bits is cut
4. after shuffle, first 1500 list items are kept
5. I have 1500 items from range

*As @r.e.s. mentioned in comments, MT has 2<sup>19937</sup>−1 possible states, that's why single run has to be held under 2080 items - to be able to reach every random permutation.*

*Also `random.sample()` seems to be an option.*

Comment: What is your source for saying there's a 20000-bit limit on the random seed length?

Comment: @r.e.s. there is nice explanation for it here: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48503151/is-there-a-maximum-character-limit-to-random-seed), also discussion on 20000b (2500B) here: [link](https://bugs.python.org/issue21470). Didn't go deep but basically it seems to be same for 3.4 - 3.8.

Comment: I think the answer at that first link is wrong, and I've posted a comment there explaining why. The discussion at the second link is interesting, but seems to concern only the default seeding, not the user-input seed.  As described in the [Python docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#bookkeeping-functions), if the input is an `int` -- which is limited in size only by available memory -- then all of its bits get used directly.

Comment: (Of course, that arbitrarily large seeds will have all of their bits used to seed the MT doesn't change the fact that the MT has "only" $2^{19937}-1$ possible states -- not enough to simulate a uniform distribution on a set of more than about $2080!$ possibilities.)

Comment: @r.e.s. about 2080 limit I know, that thing you said about no-limit I will go through. Guess I will have to dig deeper. Updating answer. Good job.

Comment: Since you're using Python, why not just use `random.sample(range(8000), 1500)`? The docs for that say the sample is returned in the order selected, so the number of possible such ordered samples is $8000!/6500!=2^{19232^-},$ which is well under the number of possible MT states ($2^{19937}-1$).

Comment: When I was writing this, I wasn't looking into source code much and I wanted F-Y which I knew was the random.shuffle. I guess this is also possibility.